# AngularJS problems with window.print()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, printing

We are building a SPA for a client, we have been working with AngularJS for several years already (haven't migrated to 2.0 yet :) ), and we have this  interesting thing going on only on webkit browsers.

Here is one of our modules with it's directive:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app.medical.reports.referrals.directives', [])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)
        .directive('medicalReferralsReportsDirector', medicalReferralsReportsDirector);

    function config() {
    }

    function run() {
    }

    function medicalReferralsReportsDirector($window, $compile, $timeout, medicalReportsService) {
        var directive = {};

        directive.restrict = "EA";
        directive.scope = true;
        directive.link = linkFn;
        directive.template = ['<div ng-include="print.printObject.templateUrl"></div>'].join('');

        return directive;

        function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function (e, data) {
                var bindToThisElement = angular.element(angular.element(element.children()[0]).children()[0]),
                    bindingFunction = $compile(bindToThisElement);

                bindingFunction(scope);

                $timeout(function () {

                    //TODO Strasen fix za webkit - STRASEN
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $window.print();
                    });
                    scope.print.printObject.startPrintRendering = false;
                    scope.$destroy();
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

We have other service that listens for an event which tells that there is something to be printed, then we append this directive (as attribute) to the parent DOM Element of the print container, then we make a request (if not in cache) for the html template (url passed in the scope property - "print.printObject.templateUrl"). 
Then on '$includeContentLoaded', we just find the DOM element and call $compile on the scope.

Everything is OK, but there is this one very interesting thing going on. Only on webkit browsers if we do not put the $window.print() function in a $timeout function it inserts a blank page after the content it should print.

This does not happen in Mozilla or Opera.

And please, this question should not be mistaken with this one - [Calling $window.print() in angularjs causes the print preview to show a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250978/calling-window-print-in-angularjs-causes-the-print-preview-to-show-a-blank-pa)
because we already found the solution/hack for the problem and we are only asking for the explanation if someone could provide it.

Thank you very much in advance...

In addition:
I almost forgot mentioning that,
   after the printing is done and the print window is removed, we destroy the scope, thus removing all references of the directive on all DOM Elements, so if you just press (Ctrl + P) or just call through command line - window.print(), right after the printing has finished and the directive has been removed, the blank page will be gone, and everything seems fine.

We tried many things, we couldn't get it to work without the $timeout function. Our guess is that it is something internal that happens in the $compile function, cause if we don't use this directive (thus don't use $compile) and just put some static content in the DOM to be printed then everything is fine :). Odd at least...

Sorry for the long post, i don't have a potato :)), but i'll have gratitude for anyone who will try giving an answer :)

Comment: try `$scope.evalAsync(function(){ })` instead of `$timeout(function(){ })`
using $timeout gives you an entire additional $digest... bad for performance and bad practice using $timeout for this purpose

Comment: also this `bindingFunction = $compile(bindToThisElement); bindingFunction(scope);` can be shortened to `$compile(bindToThisElement)(scope)`

Comment: also, you have a $timeout inside of a $timeout.... this does absolutely nothing different than if you just did one $timeout... but I'm wasting my words... don't use $timeout at all, just change it to one scope.$evalAsync

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @PatrickLawler. Thank you for the tips also we will try with evalAsync() and write again. 

On the third comment, i don't know why, but if we just use one $timeout() for the print it doesn't work. It works with one $timeout only if we use it without $destroy() in advance. Maybe because both $timeout() and $destroy() call $digest()? :S
Also if you know why are we experiencing this problem with the blank page and all that only in webkit browser, could you please elaborate a bit, it will widen our Angular and browser's rendering engines knowledge. Thanks again...

Comment: Also i just checked the documentation for $evalAsync() it says: 
"at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution" :(

Comment: evalAsync will be evaluated in the same digest cycle. the angular docs on evalAsync aren't worded very well. `"at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution" !== "an additional digest cycle will be performed"`
I'd check out this blog for more info on evalAsync http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm @Gule